# How would I solve this questions, as I don't understand?

Tags: geometry

The questions.

There are two white squares of the same size where one side is equal to 8x.

In one square, there is a circle inside where the sides of the squares are tangents to the circle at their midpoints of the sides,

In the other square, there is a smaller square inside where its edges touches the midpoints of the square's sides.

Work out the ratio of the area of the circle in the first square to the smaller square inside the square to the area of the one of the squares (which have the same area as they are the same size)

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you could try to draw the situation, to begin with...

Comment: What's the radius of the circle inside that first square?  What's the length of a side of the smaller square inside that second square?  Drawing and labeling pictures will make this much easier.

Comment: Can't parse the questions which says "ratio of area of x to y to z". Three-way ratios aren't defined.

Comment: Can't send a picture as I don't have reputation points.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, [sure they are](https://www.google.com/search?&q=three-part+ratios).  The three areas $A,B,C$ can be calculated and then the ratio $A : B : C$ can be simplified as much as possible by canceling common factors, just like with two-way ratios.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a picture.
[image]

There is enough information here to find the area of the circle, the red square and the ratio of one to the other.

Comment: What would 4x root 2x squares be tho.

Comment: Actually nevermind